# Teiid Instance in JBoss DV 6.0 cannot connect in JBDS

Tags: jboss, teiid

I am working on Teiid Designer in JBoss Developer Studio, and to perform "Execute VDB" it says that an instance of teiid must be running, so I start JBoss DV 6.0 Server, and test the connection on Teiid Instance view of the server, the tests "Test Administration Connection" and "Test JDBC Connection" says "OK", but when I try to run "Execute VDB" or any form to stablish a connection to teiid instance from the IDE, it says the same thing as is the server is not running.

You people have an idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Designer are you using? There is a known issue [1] with the latest version (9.0.2), you have to click the Refresh button in the Servers view after starting/connecting to the server.

Also, do you have the correct server set as the Default Server? You can set this in the bottom part of the Model Explorer view [2] or via the Guides view.

[1] https://issues.jboss.org/browse/TEIIDDES-2536

[2] http://docs.jboss.org/teiid/designer/9.0/user-guide/en-US/html/dive-right-in-chapter.html#server-version-status-panel